# In the Harry Dresdenverse do you have to say something to use evocation?

Tags: magic, magical-theory, the-dresden-files

In the world of Harry Dresden we always see him use *Fuego* or *Forzare* to use his evocation magic, usually shouting it in the process.  Can other Wizards say an evocation and only mouth a word?

Answer (score 11):

No, you do not have to speak, or even mouth a word, in order to cast an evocation spell.  However, performing an evocation without speaking is both dangerous and painful.

From *Fool Moon*, chapter 15, abridged:

> I stopped trying to struggle against the man who was choking me.  Instead, I grabbed his wrist and prepared to do something foolish.
>
> Magic is a kind of energy.  It is given shape by human thoughts and emotions, by imagination.  Thoughts define that shape - and words help to define those thoughts.  That's why wizards use words to help them with their spells.  Words provide a sort of insulation as the energy of magic burns through a spell caster's mind.
>
> But you can work magic without words, without insulation for your mind.  If you're not afraid of it hurting a little.
>
> I drew in my will, my exhausted fear, and focused on what I wanted.  Then I ground my teeth together and released my will with a burst of sudden energy.
>
> Two things happened.  First, a rush of blinding thought, brilliant and wild and jangling, went through my head.  My eyes swam with color, my ears with phantom sound.  My senses were assaulted with a myriad of impressions.  They were a side-effect of the energy rushing through my head.
>
> The second thing that happened was a surge of electricity gathered from the air around me to my fingertips, gripped on my attacker's wrist, and surged up through his arm and into his body.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, thats exactly what i needed! So it looks like me and my friend were right and wrong, haha. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: A similar effect happens when you use a verbal component which is in a language you understand.  For instance, an English speaker saying, "Fire" would feel the same feedback effect.

Comment: @Jeff: yep, that's all explained in the same part of the text, though I left that part out as it wasn't directly relevant to the OPs question and the section was too long to quote intact.

Comment: Definitely.  Another example happens in Ghost Story, but it's spoilerific so I won't elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

The words that wizards shout during evocations are not some magic spell formulas - they exist so you can name a concept that you have in your mind. Harry uses faux-Latin (and bit of Spanish), Molly uses Japanese etc (all those words are selected in such way, that they won't come in accidental conversation), but in the end the magic is actually in their head. In similar fashion they don't really need to use physical props i.e. circles for summoning (in "Changes" Dresden just imagines that he is making a ritual to summon Uriel - and it works), or special "blasting rod" to cast fire but it requires much more effort.

So if you ask can they cast spell mute - yes they (probably - since I don't recall any example) can but no, they couldn't use someone's else mouthing the "right word" as a focus.

Comment: Thanks, I get that it isnt like in harry potter, its just me and a friend were just getting in a small argument over whether a wizard even had to speak to use evocation. He made the Argument that it was probably harder than not speaking 'fuego' (because in "Changes" even when Harry summoned Uriel in his mind, it was harder than if he used actual props.)

Comment: There is a quote in books somewhere (I can't remember where) where Harry says that naming spell is a way to wrap a mind about a concept and staying sane, but I don't remember in which book it was

Comment: Yeah I think I remember something like that, I guess I'll just have to write it down when I re read it, haha.

Answer (score 2):

In the Dresden Files, Evocation is referred to as 'quick and dirty magic' by Harry many times. He also mentions that he has trouble controlling evocations even with his focii - Staff and Blasting Rod.

In general, he uses nonsense words, faux latin and a bit of spanish for his spells - "Feugo (fire) and Fozare (force)". When putting Murphy to sleep in 'Grave Peril' he uses "Dormius, dorme, dormius". He uses the same sleep spell to put Evelyn Derek to sleep in 'Turn Coat'.

The use of words in spells in the Dresden Files is protect the practitioners mind from the energy of the spell while it is being cast. Usually they use words from languages they do not know very well, to avoid

For example, in 'Fool Moon', when he blows the tires out on a truck full of Bezerkers, he uses a word he doesn't know.

> Then I drew in a breath, and my renewed will with it, lifted the rod in my right hand, murmured a phrase in a language I didn't know, and blew the tires off his fucking truck.

There are no examples in the series so far of Harry using Evocation without a word. The spells that he does use without words, such as communing with Elaine in 'Summer Knight' take time and focus to accomplish.

Comment: Your last paragraph isn't true; see my answer for an example.

Comment: Bah, forgot about that scene. Wish Jim would get Harry to do it again, the after effects of casting a non verbal evocation were interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The word of a spell in the Dresdenverse is just any given wizard's personal call sign for the mental construct they form to channel magic into a particular effect.  Which word it is doesn't actually matter, so long as it's not something they would commonly say (which would accidentally call the construct to mind, and thus channel the spell).

Harry actually does attempt nonverbal spells early in the series (Fool Moon, when getting jumped by Finn when they meet for the first time).  Spells can be done without words, but it is far more painful.  Using words creates a logical cause and effect that kind of shields a wizards mind from the energy he's channeling.  Just channeling the energy through will alone, especially quick and dirty as with most of Harry's evocations, gives him a wicked raw headache, and would probably fry his brain if he wasn't concentrating hard enough.  He gets good enough at it over time to call shields on raw instinct without verbalizing, although for most combat spells Harry still relies on words.

None of the wizardry props are really needed for any spell, so long as the will of the wizard is perfect.  Since that rarely ever happens, we get magic circles, rituals, candles, and most importantly we get *fuego*.